# Tilecache seeding with mapserver doesn't generate tiles

Tags: web-mapping, mapserver, ubuntu, tilecache

I'm attempting to seed my tile cache on the server for use within OpenLayers for a few zoom levels, however the script doesn't seem to be working at all and everything I try I just get the same output.

The data displays fine when I view it in a browser using OpenLayers and the cache is generated based on what I look at.

The server is running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS which has nothing but Mapserver, Apache, Tilecache, and the required libs for that installed on.

My config files are as follows -

Tilecache Config

```
[cache]
type=Disk
base=/home/tilecache

[streetview]
size=256,256
srs=EPSG:27700
type=WMS
url=http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/mapadmin/data/tm/out/comp/tm.map
layers=streets
mapfile=/home/mapadmin/data/tm/out/comp/tm.map
bbox=600000,200000,660000,30000
extension=png
mime_type=image/png
maxresolution=234.375
extent_type=loose
levels=20
expire=3600
```

Mapserver Config

```
MAP
        IMAGETYPE       PNG
        EXTENT          600000.000000 200000.000000 660000.000000 300000.000
        SIZE            800 600
        SHAPEPATH       "/home/mapadmin/data/tm/out/comp/"
        IMAGECOLOR      255 255 255

        PROJECTION
                "init=epsg:27700"
        END

        WEB
                METADATA
                        "ows_enable_request"   "*"
                        "wms_title"             "WMS Street Test"
                        "wms_onlineresource"    "http://192.168.1.126/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/mapadmin/data/tm/out/comp/tm.map&"
                        "wms_srs"               "EPSG:27700"
                END
        END

        LAYER
                NAME            streets
                STATUS          on
                TYPE            RASTER
                TILEINDEX       "tm.shp"
                TILEITEM        "LOCATION"

                PROJECTION
                        "init=epsg:27700"
                END

                METADATA
                        "wms_title"     "Streetview"
                        "wms_srs"       "EPSG:27700"
                END
        END
END
```

Output from terminal

```
mapadmin@mapserver:/etc$ sudo tilecache_seed.py "streetview" 04 09 -b "600000, 200000, 660000, 30000" -p 1 -f -c /etc/tilecache.cfg
Config file set to /etc/tilecache.cfg
###### (0, 0, 4), (16, -45, 4)
###### (0, 0, 5), (32, -90, 5)
###### (0, 0, 6), (64, -181, 6)
###### (0, 0, 7), (128, -362, 7)
###### (0, 0, 8), (256, -725, 8)
mapadmin@mapserver:/etc$
```

Any help on this would be great as it's really driving me nuts now, I've spent hours trying to work out why it's just not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a guide that is using Ordnance Survey tilecached rasters

[image]

http://www.esdmwms.no-ip.co.uk/scripts/tilecache/tilecache-2.11/indexOS27700.html

(some tiles are no longer present - seems the location has been moved/expired)

How to Guide
http://www.esdmdata.co.uk/tilecache-on-iis7-how-to

Comment: Thanks for the links, unfortunately I'm using Linux and these are based around Windows. I've managed to solve my issue after having a break though.

Comment: They are based in python which will work on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the issue with this after having a break for a while and coming back to it.

The Mapserver config needed the EXTENT parameter changing from

```
EXTENT          600000.000000 200000.000000 660000.000000 300000.000
```

to

```
EXTENT          600000.000000 200000.000000 660000.000000 300000.000000
```

Once I'd made this change I ran the command from within a new downloaded copy of Tilecache 2.11

```
sudo python tilecache_seed.py "streetview" 04 09 -b 600000.000000,200000.000000,660000.000000,300000.000000 -p 1 -f -c /etc/tilecache.cfg
```

This now appears to be generating the cache for me.

Hope that helps anyone else who's having issues :-)